# Azure Logic App IP Restrictions update through powershell

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-powershell

I have to add some IP to whitelist for azure logic app IP restrictions through powershell script.I have googled to find any command to add IP restrictions to azure logic app to whitelist those IPs but I could not find any such commands is there any way to do it through powershell?

Answer (score 0):

The access control properties are set in the [ARM template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.logic/workflows) for the app, so that is how you would update them via PowerShell. Since you already have the app created, the simplest method will be to export the template from the existing app, make your edits and then run the PowerShell commands

In particular, you need to set the accessControl property:

```
"accessControl": {
    "triggers": {
        "allowedCallerIpAddresses": [{
                "addressRange": "192.168.1.0-192.168.1.100"
            }
        ]
    },
    "actions": {
        "allowedCallerIpAddresses": [{
                "addressRange": "192.168.1.0-192.168.1.100"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Once you've made your template changes, it can be deployed with [PowerShell or the CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-deploy-azure-resource-manager-templates)

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName <Azure-resource-group-name> -TemplateUri https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/101-logic-app-create/azuredeploy.json
```

or

```
az group deployment create -g <Azure-resource-group-name> --template-uri https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/101-logic-app-create/azuredeploy.json
```